# How do you represent response time and requests-per-second in one measure?

Tags: visualization, monitoring, grafana, prometheus, metrics

I have a graph for a number of endpoint response times for a Web service. For some endpoints, high response time can be misleading because if the requests-per-second is low,  the impact is also low. Thus, I always have to check a corresponding requests-per-second graph to understand the true impact.

How can I represent response time and requests-per-second in one measure? I'd like to avoid plotting response-time and requests-per-second on one graph because I'd like to get a single measure of multiple endpoints on one graph.

Comment: can you show the plots you do now? or the sample of your data?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you want to achieve. Can you clarify what you mean by  'low impact' ? Depending on the answer you may have a look at queuing theory to see if there is a relevant metric to compute.